# How to enable ajax page load in primefaces mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsf-2, primefaces, mobile-website

How can we enable page-loading via ajax in primefaces-mobile. In jquery mobile, ajax page loading is by default, How to achieve this in primefaces-mobile[I read on primefaces website that primefaces mobile is powered by jquery mobile, then why doesn't it load the pages via ajax.].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By viewing the page-source of primefaces-mobile-web page, I found following clue

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

Now all you have to do is to **find a way to override mobileinit event, and set the above variables to true**. I simply included following script in my `h:head` tag:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = true;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = true;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
```

This served my purpose, but I am afraid, this might affect primefaces-mobile controls behaviour e.g. form submission.